# MySQL SELECT query works in PHPmyadmin, not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So, Im having a lot of trouble with executing a query in PHP. It executes well in phpmyadmin and gives me a neat list of results.

Here is the query I inserted into phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT RIGHT(`Pair`, LOCATE('_', REVERSE(`Pair`))-1) 
FROM `poloniex`
WHERE LEFT(`Pair`, 3) = 'BTC';
```

For example an entry in the Column Pair: BTC_NXT

The query should return NXT (everything right of the "_").

Now, when switching over to php while I haven't edited the query at all, I don't get any result.
The dbconnection is already established; no problems on that front.

```
$query_get_pairs = "SELECT RIGHT(`Pair`,LOCATE('_',REVERSE(`Pair`))-1) FROM `poloniex` WHERE LEFT(`Pair`, 3) = 'BTC'";
$result_get_pairs = mysqli_query($dbc,$query_get_pairs);
```

var_dump($result_get_pairs) returns an empty array.

Summary:

- `poloniex` is the table name.
- `Pair` is the column name which
  contains values like "BTC_NXT". The query should give me NXT.

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` say?

Comment: There's absolutely **NO** way that `$result_get_pairs` would be an empty array. mysqli_query returns either a mysqli statement handle, or a boolean FALSE to signify failure.

Comment: Do you mean mysqli_error($dbc)? That doesnt give me anything.

Comment: @Marc B it gives me a boolean FALSE indeed.

Comment: That means your query failed, and mysqli_error() would tell you why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching anything, your code should be like:

```
$query_get_pairs = "SELECT RIGHT(Pair,LOCATE('_',REVERSE(Pair))-1) FROM poloniex WHERE LEFT(Pair, 3) = 'BTC'";
$result_get_pairs = mysqli_query($query_get_pairs);
$myResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_get_pairs);
var_dump($myResult);
```